# ClientUtils#findAll(String selector) example code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

This CasperJS code sample (http://casperjs.org/api.html#clientutils.findAll) doesn't work. Does anyone know how to get this thing working?

```
var links;
casper.start('http://foo.bar/', function() {
    links = this.evaluate(function() {
        var elements = __utils__.findAll('a.menu');
        return Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute('href');
        });
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(links)).exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#map` instead of `Array#forEach`.